# build initramfs for different host

Tags: initramfs, cross-compilation, dracut

Cross compiling a kernel takes minutes, deploying
the thing on the target machine takes an hour.
Most of the time is spent generating the initramfs.
Both the build host and the target run Fedora which
uses dracut to that end.

It’d be great to build the initramfs along with the
kernel. Is that possible with dracut, and if so, how?

EDIT in 2023: [Looks like Fedora’s UKI infrastructure](https://lwn.net/SubscriberLink/918909/f5ca5d01fcc13783/)
will provide this kind of prebuilt, host-independent
initramfs at some point in the future, probably
even for ARM64 which is the platform on which this
question arose in the first place.

Comment: Probably not in a reliable way. If your rebuilds are taking an hour, though, you're doing something wrong. Are you rebuilding them in serial or parallel?

Comment: If you know your hardware and platform configuration is pretty much uniform across all the nodes, you might just push that down as a separate rpm

Comment: @Bratchley the rebuilds are slow due to the system running on an SD card and ``/lib/modules/$(uname -r)`` weighing 1.3 GB (the config should be as close to stock Fedora armv7hl). And it’s not parallel on a 1-core machine ;)

Comment: If the hardware and config are uniform then I would just build it once and deploy it as an rpm. Possibly including it in your kernel rpm.

Comment: @Bratchley it’s not the same kernel each time: different configs, different git revision, …

Comment: Do you have an image of each one you can chroot into? It might be faster to build the initrd in a chroot than building them on slower storage. It's just copying the binaries and config files into a compressed image. You might build the various images in chroot representations of the different variations.

Comment: Also a single core can process in parallel, just not very much. While one build is waiting on I/O another can have the CPU, etc.

Comment: @Bratchley: 1) I can’t execute the target binaries on the host;  2) the CPU is superscalar, but dracut already spawns multiple threads.

Comment: Well it sounds like the only option here would be building the kernel in a way that didn't require an initrd if that's possible.

Comment: @Blatchley I would do that without hesitating, but the requirement is to get by with as few modifications to the stock config as possible. Thanks anyways for trying!

Comment: The thing is what you're saying you're wanting to do is just conceptually impossible. You're wanting to execute commands as if they're on a machine but if you're executing them on the machine then you're obviously going to always run into the problem you're posting about. Writing some sort of dracut hook might be possible but by the time you got down working around the various problems I'm talking about, you will have probably spent more time than you saved. Building a monolithic kernel is probably for the best in this scenario.

Comment: I'm skeptical it's taking you an _hour_ to build an initrd, single core+sd or no. For reference, I can build an initrd on a VM backed by rotational media in about five minutes. Obviously SD is still going to be slower but the process we're talking about is more or less just copying files into a compressed image. The compression takes some cpu time but it's mostly about just reading files in from disk. If you were to say it takes 10-15 minutes I'd believe that though.